# Assigning static IP and domain name mapping to local server in LAN

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, local-area-network, static-ip

I have developed a web application which will be deployed in a LAN environemnt. Clients will be Computers/Android Tablets/IPAD

In order for communication between client and local server

1) need to assign a static IP to local server.
2) need a domian name mapping for that IP address in Local environment.
3) router should assign the same static IP if it gets restarted etc.

I am using a **windows XP** machine as Local server OS.

Do i need to take care of router configurations before buying one, or all routers will have same capability to perform this task.

I am not a network specialist, so Sorry if this question sounds stupid.

Thanks

Comment: I would strongly suggest developing or incorporating existing discovery mechanisms so that it doesn't matter what IP your server gets, clients can always discover the new address when they go to connect. I strongly suggest basing this on existing protocols and libraries, and documenting its functionality well for your clients.

Answer (score 2):

Consider buying router hardware on which you can install OpenWRT or a similar Linux or BSD based free software firmware. On that firmware you should configure the `dnsmasq` daemon which implements the [Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) and the [Domain Name System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System). The DHCP server part can serve both dynamic IP-addresses and static ones by hostname or MAC-address (static leases). All hosts that are configured via DHCP can be regististered in the internal DNS server automatically to make their names resolvable in the local network.

Answer (score 0):

One configuration you may wish to implement, assuming your server is switched on 24/7, would be to turn your local machine into a DNS server. You could run a virtualized linux installation with BIND installed, with network bridging configured on the virtual machine network interface. I highly recommend [VirtualBox](http://virtualbox.org).

There is a risk, however, that when the hardware goes down your network loses the lone DNS setting. To prevent that, ensure that you have at least two DNS servers set on your router interface with the primary being the IP of your developer machine. Also ensure that non-standard domain names are being set for your developer machine as using domain.com might conflict with existing internet DNS records.